# How does phase gets aligned in a superconductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking

I am trying to make an analogy between the spontaneous symmetry breaking occurring in magnetism and that of superconducvity, but I am struggling to make it precise.

In magnetism, we know that interactions are aligning the directions of all spins in the system, thus the system has a single magnetic orientation. The hamiltonian we can use to describe such a mechanism is of the form

$$
H = - J \sum_{i,j} \vec{S_i} \cdot \vec{S_j}
$$
In superconductivity, the phase of the system is said to be uniform. Can we think of the superconductivity interaction as a "phase aligning" mechanism? If so, can this be understood within BCS theory? And as a side question, what do we mean exactly when we say that the "phase" of the electrons is uniform?

Comment: In addition to many tries to explain the U(1) symmetry breaking on this website, as e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284377/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323508/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306515/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272762/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105538/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44565/16689 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/58069/16689, you may find this [Wikipedia page interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_quantum_phenomena)

Comment: Also here : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133780/16689